# Pylons resource not found

Tags: pylons

This is a beginner's question.

I created a project called fileupload using pylons. I `paster controller form`'ed a controller called form. Inside it, I render a template called form.html. Could someone tell me what url I need to type to actually see form.html?

After `paster serve --reload development.ini` I type in localhost:5000/fileupload/form and get a 404 error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through trial and error immediately after posting the question, but I'll answer it for others to see.

localhost:5000/form/index is the url I was looking for.